# Debugging a program that involves EventBus communication between multiple files

Tags: vue.js

I'm currently working on an e-mail like practice app, and struggling with figuring out how a "compose" button and saving newly sent messages in the "sent" box work.

The app looks like the attached images.

[image: sidebar and content]
[image: composing a new message]

**[The program's expected behavior]**

When a new message is sent by the "Send" button of the "New Message" composing window (after filling in the Subject and Message), the new message's info gets sent and stored in the "Sent" box on the sidebar, increasing the number of sent messages as well. (The number of sent message is set to 4, so if I send a new message it should be updated to 5)

**[Problem]**

The sent messages that are sent via the "Compose new message" window are not stored, and the number of the "Sent" messages on the sidebar doesn't get updated either.

**[What I have tried so far]**

- To see if the "Send" button actually reacted to a click by setting a console.log statement (and confirmed that it did react to a click)

(like this)

```
methods:{
            sendMessage(){
                console.log('sendMessage called!');
                eventBus.$emit('sentMessage', {
                    message:{
                        subject: this.message.subject,
                        content: this.message.content,
                        isDeleted: false,
                        type: 'outgoing',
                        date: moment(),
                        from: {
                            name: 'Bo Andersen',
                            email: 'info@codingexplained.com'
                        },
                        attachments: []
                    }
                });
                console.log('eventBus called!');
            }
        }
```

- To see if the eventBus was called in the App.vue file by setting a console.log statement (and confirmed that it dit get called)

(like this)

```
created(){
            eventBus.$on('sentMessage', (data) => {
                console.log('eventBus called on created in App.vue!');
                let temp = [data.message];
                this.message = temp.concat(this.messages.slice(0));
                console.log('new message concatinated!');
            });

            eventBus.$on('refreshMessages', () => {
            //    console.log('page refresh got called!')
                let randomIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * randomMessages.length);
                let temp = [randomMessages[randomIndex]];
                this.messages = temp.concat(this.messages.slice(0));
            //    console.log('page refreshed!');
            });
        },
```

**[QUESTION]**

Even though I suspected that some parts of the program were not communicating with each other well, I haven't been successful in finding out any communication flaw.

**What else should I look into?**

**[Files that are involved in this program's src folder]**

- App.vue (consists of sidebar component and content component. )
- Compose.vue (responsible for composing a new message)
- Content.vue (corresponds to the right side of the attached image)
- Important.vue
- Inbox.vue
- main.js
- Messages.vue (manages the message information)
- Sent.vue
- Sidebar.vue (corresponds to the profile image, name, email address, compose button, inbox, sent, important, trash that are displayed on the left side in the attached image.)
- Trash.vue
- ViewMessage.vue

**[Some parts of the code to show you some details]**

App.vue

```
<template>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="mail-box">
            <!-- v-bind directives -->
            <app-sidebar :messages="messages"></app-sidebar>
            <app-content :messages="messages"></app-content>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
    import Sidebar from './Sidebar.vue';
    import Content from './Content.vue';
    import messages from './data/messages';
    import randomMessages from './data/random-messages';
    import { eventBus } from './main';

    export default {
        data(){
            return{
                messages: messages
            };
        },
        created(){
            eventBus.$on('sentMessage', (data) => {
                console.log('eventBus called on created in App.vue!');
                let temp = [data.message];
                this.message = temp.concat(this.messages.slice(0));
                console.log('new message concatinated!');
            });

            eventBus.$on('refreshMessages', () => {
            //    console.log('page refresh got called!')
                let randomIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * randomMessages.length);
                let temp = [randomMessages[randomIndex]];
                this.messages = temp.concat(this.messages.slice(0));
            //    console.log('page refreshed!');
            });
        },
        components: {
            appSidebar: Sidebar,
            appContent: Content
        }
    }
</script>
```

Sidebar.vue

```
<template>
    <aside class="sm-side">
        <div class="user-head">
            <img src="src/assets/images/profile.jpg">

            <div class="user-name">
                <h5>Bo Andersen</h5>
                <span class="email-address">info@codingexplained.com</span>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="compose-wrapper">
            <app-compose></app-compose>
        </div>

        <ul class="inbox-nav">
            <li :class="{ active: activeView == 'app-inbox' }">
                <a href="#" @click.prevent="navigate('app-inbox', 'Inbox')">   <!-- 'tag name' and 'title' as the parameters of navigate --> 
                    <i class="fa fa-inbox"></i>Inbox <span class="label label-danger pull-right">{{ unreadMessages.length }}</span>
                </a>
            </li>

            <li :class="{ active: activeView == 'app-sent' }">
                <a href="#" @click.prevent="navigate('app-sent', 'Sent')">
                    <i class="fa fa-envelop-o"></i>Sent <span class="label label-default pull-right">{{ sentMessages.length }}</span>
                </a>
            </li>

            <li :class="{ active: activeView == 'app-important' }">
                <a href="#" @click.prevent="navigate('app-important', 'Important')">
                    <i class="fa fa-bookmark-o"></i>Important <span class="label label-warning pull-right">{{ importantMessages.length }}</span>
                </a>
            </li>

            <li :class="{ active: activeView == 'app-trash' }">
                <a href="#" @click.prevent="navigate('app-trash', 'Trash')">
                    <i class=" fa fa-trash-o"></i>Trash <span class="label label-default pull-right">{{ trashedMessages.length }}</span>
                </a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </aside>
</template>

<script>
    // needs to be curly braces because we'll potentiall export multiple objects or values 
    import { eventBus } from './main';
    import Compose from './Compose.vue';

    export default {
        props:{
            messages:{
                type: Array,
                required: true
            }
        },
        created(){
            eventBus.$on('changeView', (data) => {
              this.activeView = data.tag; 
            });
        },
        data(){
          return{
              activeView: 'app-inbox'
          };
        },
        methods:{
            // tag name and title
            navigate(newView, title) {
                eventBus.$emit('changeView', {
                    tag: newView,
                    title: title
                });
            }
        },
        computed:{
            unreadMessages(){
                return this.messages.filter(function(message){
                    return (message.type == 'incoming' && !message.isRead && !message.isDeleted)
                });
            },
            sentMessages(){
                return this.messages.filter(function(message){
                    return (message.type == 'outgoing' && !message.isDeleted)
                });
            },
            importantMessages(){
                return this.messages.filter(function(message){
                    return (message.type == 'incoming' && message.isImportant === true && !message.isDeleted);
                });
            },
            trashedMessages(){
                return this.messages.filter(function(message){
                    return message.isDeleted === true;
                });
            }
        },
        components: {
            appCompose: Compose
        }

    }
</script>
```

Compose.vue

```
<template>
    <div>
        <a href="#composeModal" data-toggle="modal" class="btn btn-compose">Compose</a>

        <div aria-hidden="true" role="dialog" tabindex="-1" id="composeModal" class="modal fade" style="display: none;">
            <div class="modal-dialog">
                <div class="modal-content">
                    <div class="modal-header">
                        <button aria-hidden="true" data-dismiss="modal" class="close" type="button">&times;</button>
                        <h4 class="modal-title">New Message</h4>
                    </div>

                    <div class="modal-body">
                        <form role="form" class="form-horizontal" @submit.prevent="sendMessage">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label class="col-lg-2 control-label" for="subject">Subject</label>
                                <div class="col-lg-10">
                                    <input type="text" id="subject" class="form-control" v-model="message.subject">
                                </div>
                            </div>

                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label class="col-lg-2 control-label" for="message">Message</label>
                                <div class="col-lg-10">
                                    <textarea rows="10" cols="30" class="form-control" id="message" v-model="message.content"></textarea>
                                </div>
                            </div>

                            <div class="form-group">
                                <div class="col-lg-offset-2 col-lg-10">
                                    <button class="btn btn-send" type="submit">Send</button>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </form>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
    import { eventBus} from './main';
    import moment from 'moment';

    export default{
        data(){
            return {
                message: {
                    subject: '',
                    content: ''
                }
            };
        },
        methods:{
            sendMessage(){
                console.log('sendMessage called!');
                eventBus.$emit('sentMessage', {
                    message:{
                        subject: this.message.subject,
                        content: this.message.content,
                        isDeleted: false,
                        type: 'outgoing',
                        date: moment(),
                        from: {
                            name: 'Bo Andersen',
                            email: 'info@codingexplained.com'
                        },
                        attachments: []
                    }
                });
                console.log('eventBus called!');
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

**UPDATED AFTER RECEIVING COMMENTS**

App.vue

```
<template>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="mail-box">
            <!-- v-bind directives -->
            <app-sidebar :messages="messages"></app-sidebar>
            <app-content :messages="messages"></app-content>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
    import Sidebar from './Sidebar.vue';
    import Content from './Content.vue';
    import messages from './data/messages';
    import randomMessages from './data/random-messages';
    import { eventBus } from './main';

    export default {
        data(){
            return{
                messages: messages
            };
        },
        created(){
            // Save the component to a local variable for use in event callbacks
            var that = this;

            eventBus.$on('sentMessage', (data) => {
                // notice the differences between these two objects
                console.log(this, that); 

                console.log('eventBus called on created in App.vue!');
                let temp = [data.message];
           //     this.message = temp.concat(this.messages.slice(0));  // was originally using this
                that.message = temp.concat(that.messages.slice(0));   // this got replaced with that
                console.log('new message concatinated!');
            });

            eventBus.$on('refreshMessages', () => {
            //    console.log('page refresh got called!')
                let randomIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * randomMessages.length);
                let temp = [randomMessages[randomIndex]];
                this.messages = temp.concat(this.messages.slice(0));
            //    console.log('page refreshed!');
            });
        },
        components: {
            appSidebar: Sidebar,
            appContent: Content
        }
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're seeing the `console.log` messages when they are uncommented in App.vue for `eventBus.$on('refreshMessages')` and `eventBus.$on('sentMessage')` it looks like a scoping issue to me.

When using an event bus, `this` in the context of your event handler is the `eventBus` object itself, not the component. You can save the component `this` to a local variable and use it in your event handler functions. Something like this:

```
created(){
  // Save the component to a local variable for use in event callbacks
  var that = this;

  eventBus.$on('sentMessage', (data) => {
      // notice the differences between these two objects
      console.log(this, that); 

      console.log('eventBus called on created in App.vue!');
      let temp = [data.message];
      that.message = temp.concat(that.messages.slice(0));
      console.log('new message concatinated!');

  });

  eventBus.$on('refreshMessages', () => {
  //    console.log('page refresh got called!')
      let randomIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * randomMessages.length);
      let temp = [randomMessages[randomIndex]];
      that.messages = temp.concat(that.messages.slice(0));
  //    console.log('page refreshed!');
  });
},
```

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. I tried saving the component to a local variable as you shown, but the result of unfortunately the same. I also tried to find differences between "this" and "that", but the contents of those two looked identical on console, like "$attrs: Object", "$children: (2) [VueComponent, VueComponent]" etc. What kind of difference do you expect to see between them in console?

Comment: Can you post your code? Are you sure that you are assigning the "that" variable outside of the eventBus function?

Comment: I've added "UPDATED AFTER RECEIVING COMMENTS App.vue" part at the end of my original post. Is there any other part of the code that you need to take a look at?